# mod rewrite not working in subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

Our hostprovider updated our VPS to new compile of php5 and a problem rised up.

Our main site is working on wordpress just fine (has its own `.htaccess`) using `mod_rewrite` for pretty links, but in a subdirectory we have implemented video community (wich has its own `.htaccess` using mod rewrite) using other cms.

It seems like wordpress `.htaccess`  does not allow rewrite rules in a `/video/` subdirectory. If we delete wordpress `.htaccess`, our video community runs fine, but than wordpress site stops working.

Comment: Does rewriting finally not work in the sub directory or does it just not work as expected? Can you post a simplified non working test?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: here is a link to our video community: http://vozniski-izpit.com/video/ If you click on a video it gives a wordpress 404 error

Comment: we have fixed it, so if anyone else needs a code for /video/.htaccess just ad this line: RewriteBase /video/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following **in front** of the WP-rules in the .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteRule ^video/ - [L]
```

Comment: I tried inserting your line but it did not work...                    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^video/ - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress